# tinymce single quote attributes and don't convert double quotes in attributes

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am using a solution that is embedding json code for an attribute value for which I am inserting  the HTML into TinyMCE. The issue is that TinyMCE is converting my attribute single quotes to double quotes. It is also converting my json double quotes in the attribute values to html entity (&quot).

I can't seem to find anywhere in the TinyMCE documentation on how to set the attribute quote type from double quote to single quotes and how to disable it from converting double quotes in the attributes to be converted from double quote to (&quot)